# Flask ORM deal with empty values -> treat as a lowest value or replace by 0

Tags: python, flask, orm

I have script to join to tables `Prospect` and `Campaign` base on `campaign_id`.
Next I added a few neccesary columns to my output also window function `rank()`.

```
Prospect.query.join(
        Campaign, Campaign.id == Prospect.campaign_id
    ).add_columns(
        Campaign.id,
        Campaign.number,
        Campaign.number * Prospect.number_1,
        sqlalchemy.func.rank().over(
            order_by=[(Offers_budget.number * Prospect.number_1).desc(), Prospect.number_1.desc()],
            partition_by=Campaign.id),
    ).all()
```

I have trouble with my results. In columns `number` I have `null` and then query represent it as a bigest value. I would like to replace `null` by 0. Or I would like to function `rank` represent `null` as a lowest value.
Is this possible to do this in query or do I need to create logic outside of query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Result was using `coalesce`. This function returns the first of it's arguments that are not null. SO as a second argument I provide `0`.
It looks that:

```
Prospect.query.join(
        Campaign, Campaign.id == Prospect.campaign_id
    ).add_columns(
        Campaign.id,
        Campaign.number,
        Campaign.number * Prospect.number_1,
        sqlalchemy.func.rank().over(
            order_by=[(coalesce(Campaign.number, 0) * Prospect.number_1).desc(), Prospect.number_1.desc()],
            partition_by=Campaign.id),
    ).all()
```